# Prevent several clicks on a link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, click

I'd like to allow user click once in each link only. This is to avoid further problems with tabs and other stuff, and to keep the control over the system I'm working on.

So, I tried to use "one" method, but not seems to work, only the alert I've putted in:

> $(window).load(function(){
>
> $('.lockit').one('click', function(){alert('you cannot click here
>   again'); } );
>
> });

Any idea about how to proceed? I'm using JQuery 1.8.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does doing an .off() within an .on() work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only have one link which needs to be blocked,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    $(".block-link").on('click', function(e) {
        if(clicked) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('You can only click once');
        } else {
            clicked = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Otherwise if you want to do this for every link with class `.blocked-link`,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".blocked-link").each(function() {
        // Set initial data attribute
        $(this).data('clicked', 0);
        $(this).on('click', function(e) {
            if($(this).data('clicked') == 1) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('You can only click this link once');
                return false;
            } else {
                $(this).data('clicked', 1);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

jsFiddle for multiple links: http://jsfiddle.net/3C63m/

---

**EDIT: Include custom onClick functions**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".blocked-link").each(function() {
        // Set initial data attribute
        $(this).data('clicked', 0);
        $(this).on('click', function(e) {
            if($(this).data('clicked') == 1) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('You can only click this link once');
                return false;
            } else {
                $(this).data('clicked', 1);
                /* PLACE YOUR onClick ACTIONS HERE */
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: for some reason, won't work on my file. But works fine outside the file. My links are using onClick to call a action. This can interrupt your script above?

Comment: @LucasHaas Yes, it may interrupt the script. You should move whatever functions you require onClick into the function above. I will edit it to reflect where you should place your functions

Answer (score 1):

You could try .preventDefault function.

```
var count = 0;
$('.lockit').one('click', function( event ){
  alert('you cannot click here again');
  count++;

  if ( count > 0 ) {
   event.preventDefault;
   }

 });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You're probably only adding a handler to an existing one.
  *HTML*

```
<button class="lockit" type="button" onclick="alert('Click')">One</button>
```

*JS*

```
$('.lockit').on('click', function(){
this.onclick="";
} );
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/LB9by/)**

Comment: Can't do that, because onClick is already busy to call a bootstrap tab.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
$('.lockit').on('click', function(){
        alert('you cannot click here again'); 
        $(this).unbind('click');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to it when it is clicked. Then check if it has the class when clicked. If so do not show alert.

```
$('.lockit').click(function(e){
    var aTag = $(this);
    if(aTag.hasClass('clicked'))
        return false;

    alert('you cannot click here again')
    aTag.addClass('clicked')
});
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzPqw/1/)**